# Stop further execution when a SWT shell is opened

Tags: java, multithreading, shell, swt

SWT View say "CalculateView" is created and opened and it is followed by certain lines of code say "change()". SWT shell is disposed only when save button in CalculateView shell is clicked. The "change() method code makes some changes in some variables that affects the code in the save button of the shell. So I need to stop the execution of the code after shell.open() until save button in CalculateView is clicked.

```
Shell shell =  =new Shell().
CalculateView view= new CalculateView(shell);
shell.open();
change();
```

Inside CalculateView I have save button.

```
  CalculateView()
    {
    ToolItem save = new ToolItem();
    save.addSelectionListener({
    @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                getshell().close();
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand the execution will be continue if you don't put below lines and window will be destroyed.

```
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
```